# почему во всех языках так много исключений?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Почему во всех языках так много исключений и путаницы? Почему нет ни одного человеческого языка, который мог бы быть описан простыми правилами и схемами без исключений или почти без исключений?

Comment: Есть эсперанто и другие искусственные языки - в них нет исключений и нет путаницы, описаны простыми правилами и схемами без исключений. И даже не "почти".

Встречный вопрос: почему дерево никогда не растет симметрично? Всегда какие-то ветки растут "не так", а у некоторых и ствол кривой...

Comment: Да, я знаю про эсперанто. Но если он так прост и хорош во всех отношениях, почему его используют так мало людей? Ведь этот язык существует уже больше века

Comment: Дело тут не в языке – сложности или простоте его изучения. Вот вы лично почему еще не изучили эсперанто? Думаю, ответ будет примерно таким: вот если все начнут изучать, тогда и я буду. И получается отрицательная обратная связь: мы не учим, потому что почти никто не говорит, поэтому количество говорящих не растет, поэтому мы не учим.  Грубо говоря, эсперанто – просто хобби для энтузиастов, как собирание марок или выращивание цветов. Простота – этого мало, нужен еще смысл. Зачем эсперанто, когда в ходу английский? К тому же, простота эсперанто сильно преувеличивается.

Comment: Ну да, конечно, жалко тратить силы и время на язык, которым почти никто не пользуется, лучше действительно учить английский или испанский. Сейчас английский это стандарт международного общения. Хотя, в пост-совке наверное, до сих пор русский используется для межнационально общения. Но его роль скорей всего снижается.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что это естественным образом сложившиеся языки - их не конструировали по централизованно заданным правилам и они подвержены влиянию случайных факторов. Правила же выводятся из закономерностей, выявленных в уже существующем языке. Обычно чем проще правило, формулируемое для удобств обучения, тем больше из него исключений. В некоторой степени поддаётся регламентированию письменная составляющая языка, особенно пунктуация, где много условностей, которые можно принимать, не искажая сложившегося разговорного языка (хотя, напр., в русском требования повсеместно двустороннего обособления оборотов могут приводить к запятым, противоречащим интонации).

Comment: А почему никто до сих пор не сделал искусственно созданного языка из уже существующего? Ну то есть взять язык с нормальным произношением и четкими правилами чтения, например, испанский или итальянский и максимально его упростить, чтобы его можно было описать в простых правилах с минимумом исключений? Если так сделать, в чем будут самые большие недостатки полученного языка? Ведь язык эволюционирует, то есть по идее он должен упрощаться, но чем больше он упрощается, тем больше в нем исключений. Раз в языке появляются исключения, значит, они для чего-то нужны.

Comment: Уже так сделано, и сравнительно давно: про искусственный язык эсперанто уже сказали в комментах, он во многом приближен к испанскому. Недостаток такого языка заключается в его относительной ненужности: распространение получил живой язык, английский, а язык эсперанто так и не вышел за пределы узких клубов - за ним нет литературы и пр. элементов культуры.

Comment: Кажется, я понял, в чем тут фишка. Упрощая что-то одно, практически неизбежно усложняется что-то другое. Я почитал историю с языком "идо" и понял эту истину)) Невозможно сделать язык простым во всех отношениях. То есть возможно, но такой язык будет примитивен и беден до безобразия. Нормальный,развитый язык неизбежно будет иметь кучу правил и исключений из них.

Comment: Нет, эсперанто развитый язык, но исключений в нем нет.  Литература тоже имеется, причем довольно обширная.

Comment: >>  *Раз в языке появляются исключения, значит, они для чего-то нужны* Раз в комнате появляется пыль, значит, она для чего-то нужна?